# Twitter Bootstrap's Button Border's Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I customized my button's border color using this css code:

```
.btn:focus { 
    border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8);
}
```

Here's what I expect:

- While the button is being pressed:

[image: While button is pressed]

- After the button has been pressed:

[image: After button is pressed]

I want the button's border to remain green even after being pressed. The button's border color must be changed back to default, when the other button is clicked/focused. How should I do it?

**SOLUTION:**

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active
{ 
    border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
 }
```

Comment: i think you need to look at adding code for the `:active` state and `:focus` state, that also looks like potentially the `box-shadow` style not just `border-color`

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the outline attribute to none as it may be overlapping your border